# Vector writing a blank index value

Tags: c

I have a vector variable. I would like to add a value of 10 to this variable. I want to delete a number from the value I added and write a new value. The value that I gave you must go to the part I erased. Can you help with this?

Example:

```
int id = Iter_Free();
VectorWrite(id, 123);

id = Iter_Free();
VectorWrite(id, 124);

id = Iter_Free();
VectorWrite(id, 125);

-> Vector Content: 123[ID: 0], 124[ID: 1], 125[ID: 2]

Iter_Remove(id, 124);

-> Vector Content: 123[ID: 0], 125[ID: 2]

VectorWrite(id, 128);

-> Vector Content: 123[ID: 0], 128[ID: 1], 125[ID: 2]
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What I want is like the example, but I couldn't.

Comment: What precisely is not working? We'll help you with your code when you're stuck and can't get it to work, but we're not going to do the assignment for you.

Comment: I don't have a code like that. I have prepared this code for illustrative purposes. How do I write a code like this? So I want to find an empty number in Vector and write a value there.

Comment: You define your vector (`typedef struct { ... } Vector;), allocate memory dynamically with `malloc` and free it again with `free`, add numbers by setting the respective value and finding values by comparing them with `==`. Typically a vector keeps track of its size and possibly the amount of current elements and moves the elements to fit the gaps after you delete one. Happy coding.